# Bootstrap DatePicker not working with Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datatables

No console errors, just doesn't work.

```
if (typeof (data.maintExpiry) === 'undefined') { 
    data.maintExpiry = '01-01-1970' 
}
if (typeof (data.maintExpiry) === 'undefined') { 
    data.maintExpiry = new Date('01-01-1970') 
} //also doesn't work

someColumn = '<span>test</span>'
maintExpiry = '<div class="input-append date" class="datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">'
maintExpiry += '<input style="display: inline;padding-left: 20px;" size="16" type="text" value="' + data.maintExpiry + '">'
maintExpiry += '<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span></div>'
someOtherColumn = '<span>test2</span>'
...
$('#myReport').dataTable().fnAddData([
    someColumn,
    maintExpiry,
    someOtherColumn
]);
```

Then in the document.ready:

```
$('#myReport').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        $('.datepicker').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
    }
});
```

The reason I ended up putting datepicker() in the fnDrawCallback function of dataTables is because I previously had issues with bootstrap popovers only applying to elements on the first page.  This ensured they applied to everything on the page every time the page was changed.  I also tried datepicker() outside of this with no luck.

I'm doing the each() function since the bootstrap datepicker docs show using an id selector and since these are dynamically generated I was hoping I could do it via the class.  I also simply tried $('.datepicker').datepicker() but that didn't work either.

Again, no console errors or anything.  It looks like it should but zero behavior on click in IE and Chrome.  Well, I can type in the input box...

**update** I just realized I had the class definition twice. I  consolidated the two and now I get a console error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined - bootstrap-datepicker.js:393  Investigating...

**update 2** Looks like I'm trying to populate the field with an invalid date.  I've added the line below.  Any ideas how I can set a default date if there is no date returned?

Comment: make sure... your data.maintExpiry is in rigth format... seperated by -